# How to define the database for ActiveRecord migrations when database is hosted

Tags: ruby, postgresql, heroku, activerecord

I am using a [non-Rails Active Record migration tool](https://github.com/thuss/standalone-migrations), and a [hosted Postgres database from Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-to-heroku-postgres-databases-from-outside-of-heroku).  My dev environment is on Digital Ocean.  The production code will be on Heroku.

According to the docs, it seems that the way to connect is through the `Database_URL`, however, I don't see that as an option for the config.yml file based on the documentation.

What do I put in the development config and production config given the above conditions?

When I create my own tables manually, without using the standalone-migration gem, I used:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(ENV['POSTGRES_URL'])
```

but I don't see a similar option to just provide a single URL.

Can I just do the following?

```
# config.yml

development:
  adapter: pg
  database: ENV['POSTGRES_URL']


production:
  adapter: pg
  database: ENV['POSTGRES_URL']
```

Comment: if you click on the app from the heroku web console, then click "resources" then "postgres" then "database credentials", you will see a URI. Try passing that as a string to `establish_connection`, or you can leave the code the way it is and run `env POSTGRES_URL="<the url>" rails s`

Comment: It should act like Rails itself, so you can write `development: "postgres://..."` or define an environment variable `DATABASE_URL`

Comment: It works with establish_connection, that's what I was saying.  But I meant using the config file when using `standalone-migration`

Comment: @slowjack2k -- that would go in the development: configuration and just leave the rest of the values blank in the YAML file?

Comment: It goes into the database.yml file. You can use this for the development, protuction or test attribute.

Comment: Thanks, would it look like my edited version above?